# mlma package error: Error in if (a[i] > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I have a dataframe very similar to this:

```
structure(list(Impuls = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    Eat_expect = structure(c(2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4), format.spss = "F1.0", display_width = 11L), 
    BINGE = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), format.spss = "F8.2", display_width = 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The only difference is that my full dataset goes on into the thousands, so apologies I cannot post my full set.

I'm attempting to run MLM on this using the package `mlma` in R. I thought I was writing the function properly, but it seems I may not have.

```
library(mlma)
mlma_impulse <- mlma(y=meal_impulse_only$BINGE, x=meal_impulse_only$parameter$Impuls, m=meal_impulse_only$parameter$Eat_expect)
```

Running that yielded the error "Error in if (a[i] > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Apparently, I don't need to specify `$parameter`

So, I changed things up and ran this:

```
mlma_impulse <- mlma(y = meal_impulse_only$BINGE,
                     x = meal_impulse_only$Impuls,
                     m = meal_impulse_only$Eat_expect)
```

I still get the same error. I have no NA's in my full dataset. I'm not entirely certain what the error is referring to, so I'm not sure where to begin debugging.

Does anyone have experience with `mlma` and know what I might try out here? Could it do with having to specify the levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are keeping `data1 = NULL` (by default) then you must give the `level` parameter to the `mlma()` function. Here is the code using the sample data in the package:

```
data(sim.111)

#reproducing the error
mlma(y=sim.111$y, x=sim.111$x, m=sim.111$m)
#Error in if (a[i] > 1) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

mlma(y=sim.111$y, x=sim.111$x, m=sim.111$m, level=sim.111$level)
```

Comment: Ok, great. This was the issue I had thought it would be I just wasn't exactly sure.